# Selecting rows from table by applying conditions from conditions table

Tags: sql

Data on which conditions to be applied

```
ID   business   has_agreement     flag_type 
---- ----------- --------------- -----
118      99         YES             1 
119      99         YES             2 
120     100         YES             3  
121     100         YES             1  
122     100         NO              2
abcd    2300        YES             4
' '     788          NO             1
```

Conditions table:

```
condition_id    condition_set    sequence_id    field_name      operator    
value
1                PRE-3               1               ID           !=    NULL
1                PRE-3               2               ID           !=    ""
2                PRE-3               1              business      !=    NULL
2                PRE-3               2              business      !=    ""
2                PRE-3               3              business      >=    100
3                PRE-3               1              has_agreement !=    NULL
3                PRE-3               2              has_agreement !=""
3                PRE-3               3              has_agreement ='YES'
4                PRE-3               1              flag_type     !=   NULL
4                PRE-3               2              flag_type     !=    ""
4                PRE-3               3              flag_type=    1
```

my sample output should be like

```
ID   business   has_agreement     flag_type 
---- ---------------------------------------
121    100        YES                1
```

Comment: Look into dynamic SQL

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What you are trying to do is not really appropriate for SQL.